# SQL Server Count rows having specific Values & Also count child rows with same specific field

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, row

Table is look like this

```
CREATE TABLE [CONTENTS].[ID] 
(
    [ID]          NVARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [NAME]        NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [CONTENT]     NVARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [PARENT_ID]   NVARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [TYPE]        INT             NOT NULL,
    [SHARED]      INT             NOT NULL,
    [CREATED]     DATETIME        NULL,
    [ICON]        VARBINARY (MAX) NULL,
    [UPDATED]     DATETIME        NULL,
    [TASK_STATUS] INT             NULL
);
```

[image]

- If the column `Type` is 2 with specific value of `ID`, then I need to count that row.
- If the column `Type` is 1 then it will be the parent of another row (child row)

Also I want to get the count of all the child rows for the ID.

Finally I want to SUM all the rows count.

Consider the below Table for example.

```
ID    NAME    PARENT_ID    TYPE
111   A        000          1
222   B        111          1
333   C        111          2
444   D        111          2
555   E        222          2
```

The ID → 111 having row counts with type 2 is **3**.
(i.e) 222 is Child of 111 having the type 2 also added.

Expected Result: **COUNT 3**

Comment: Sample data and desired results in tabular format in the question would be helpful.

Comment: Provide your result, how should it look? Will be helpful to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the complete solution but may give you an idea

```
//It will return 1 or 0 if id is unique
select count(*) from tablex where type = 2 and id = x;

//To get count of child rows with parent id
select tablex.id, tablexb.child_count from tablex INNER JOIN (select parent_id, count(*) as child_count from tablex group by parent_id) as tablexb ON tablex.id = tablexb.parent_id where tablex.type = 1;
```